# I cant set array with variables of my NSObject class

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to figure out how to set array with variables of other class. I have `NSObject` class named myObject, where I did declare variables myInt and mySecondInt of `int` type.

Then I import myObject and tried to set an array like this:

```
MyObject *object = [[MyObject alloc]init];

    object.myInt = 50;
    object.mySecondInt = 15;

    object.array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:object.mySecondInt,object.myInt, nil];
```

And then I got an error: implicit conversion of `'int'` to `'id'` is disallowed with arc

Please help me to solve this, I'm learning objective-c and I wish to know how to manage with variables of other class.

Comment: See my answer which definitely solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSArray` holds the objects, myInt and mySecondInt are int values, not an object. You can typecast it into `NSNumber` or `NSString`. If you typecast it into `NSString` then access its `intValue` when using it.
Another way is to add the whole object in the array & then retrieve the object from the array & then access its entities which is better solution instead of adding individual entity.

Answer (score 2):

For primitives, you need a wrapper class to allow them to be stored as objects.

Ex.

```
[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:object.mySecondInt],[NSNumber numberWithInt:object.myInt], nil];
```

`NSArray` stores `id`'s, which are generic pointers (object references). Primitives don't fall under this category and Objective-C does not support autoboxing.

Comment: Thank you John, now i get it, i just wonder why i cant declare int like that : @property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber myInt; it warn me with error..

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban You mean NSNumber *myInt?

Comment: Yes, when i did that i get more error, for example i can't set it like this - object.myInt = 50; when declare as NSNumber instead of just int

Comment: At that point, object.myInt is an NSNumber. There is **no autoboxing**. You can't assign an `int` to an `NSNumber`. `object.myInt = 50` should be changed to `object.myInt = [NSNumber numberWithInt:50]`

Comment: Is there is any reason i should use primitive variables, if i could easily store any number as NSNumber? Like float, double etc..

Comment: Yes, the main purpose of NSNumber is to box primitive numbers in an object. Besides that, primitives provide the functionality. See [here](http://objcolumnist.com/2009/05/31/nsnumber-what-is-the-point/).

Answer (score 2):

NSArray can only hold objects(instance of NSObject or its subclass), but myInt and mySecondInt is C int value, not object.

You can do this:

```
object.array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:object.mySecondInt],[NSNumber numberWithInt:object.myInt], nil];
```

Or if you use new Xcode, you can simply write like this:

```
object.array = @[@50,@15];
```